# SQL, if condition is met - update, if not, return one column from DB

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, adodb

I am trying to create an excel storage management interface for Prestashop and I would like to avoid orders larger than the quantity in stock.

I would like to achieve this: when I create an order for 100pcs in excel, I will send the query to the database and subtract this number from the available quantity. If the quantity is less than the order then the current quantity is returned and I can process it in VBA.

This would be possible if I would send 2 queries, first to check if the quantity > order and then run the update, however there might be some orders happening for this product from different interfaces and the quantity might change between the 2 queries.

I am looking for either a general advice how could be this achieved or specific upgrade/change in the VBA code or SQL query.

- Is there a way to do this in one query?
- If not, how can I lock this database column between the SQL SELECT and the subsequent UPDATE?

My current query (SQL_Update):

```
UPDATE ps_stock_available 
SET quantity = 
    CASE 
        WHEN id_product IN (SELECT id_product from ps_product 
                            WHERE reference=?) 
           THEN quantity -? 
        WHEN id_product IN (SELECT id_product from ps_product 
                            WHERE reference=?) 
           THEN quantity -? 
    END 
WHERE 
    id_product IN (SELECT id_product from ps_product 
                   WHERE reference IN ( ?,?))
```

This query will be generated in VBA and then send to the server so the query might contain more items (stored in CPL_arr). I am executing the query like this:

```
With Cm
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = SQL_Update
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    '### fill 1st part of the SQL query (reference and quantity) ###
    For i = 1 To CPL_arr_size
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, CPL_arr(i, 1))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, CPL_arr(i, 2))
    Next i
    '### fill 2nd part of the SQL query (reference)
    For i = 1 To CPL_arr_size
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, CPL_arr(i, 1))
    Next i
    .Execute
End With
```

EDIT:

Reference is basically the product code

CPL_arr is populated from a column in the excel file. CPL_arr_size is the number of the filled rows in this column.

```
GET_CPL_arr_size = wsDodat.Range(Cells(firstRow, 8), Cells(lastRow, 8)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

This array contains the reference and the number of items ordered (ex.: CPL_arr(VP16A,10))

```
For i = firstRow To lastRow
    
    If (wsDodat.Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString) And (wsDodat.Cells(i, 8) <> vbNullString) Then
    j = j + 1
    temp_CPL_arr(j, 1) = wsDodat.Cells(i, 1).Value
    temp_CPL_arr(j, 2) = wsDodat.Cells(i, 8).Value
    End If
    
    If j = CPL_arr_size Then
    i = lastRow
    End If
Next i
```

EDIT2:

I think I have figured out the SQL part (only a concept with 1 product), thx @Parfait for the draft with the stored procedure, to be honest, I don't know why the SELECT part returns the quantity only when the order is greater than the quantity but it wokrs. Now I still need to figure out how to save the return value of the stored procedure to a variable in excel.

```
PROCEDURE `Test`(
    IN `Order` INT)
BEGIN 
        UPDATE ps_stock_available
        SET quantity =
            case
            when id_product IN (SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE reference='VP16A') AND (quantity > Order) then quantity-Order
        END 
        WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product from ps_product WHERE reference IN ('VP16A'));
    
    SELECT ps_stock_available.quantity
    FROM ps_product
    INNER JOIN ps_stock_available ON ps_product.id_product =ps_stock_available.id_product
    WHERE (ps_product.reference='VP16A') AND (ps_stock_available.quantity < 10000);
    
    END
```

Comment: `I would like to avoid orders larger than the quantity in stock.` sounds like a typical problem solved with a [check constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint)

Comment: And row-level locking.

Comment: Please post the `SELECT` query or how `CPL_arr_size` is populated.

Comment: @DFSFOT this would help to avoid having negative numbers in the quantity table, but I still don't know how I would return the actual quantity when the update is blocked by the constrain. Thx for highlighting the concept of CHECK constrain.

Comment: @Parfait I have updated the description for the CPL_arr_size